# If I'm happy with OS X running on VMware, do I really have to buy a Mac to be able to develop for App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, vmware, virtual-machine

I'm on Windows and I've got the latest version of OS X (10.7.4) running as a virtual machine on VMware Workstation. Everything works just perfect, including the latest version of Xcode. Things are very smooth and, unlike one would imagine, there's almost no sluggish behavior. I find working on projects being pretty efficient with the combined power of all the software installed on the two operating systems, which happily communicate through the VMware's shared folder. iOS devices connect via USB to the virtual machine's iTunes and Xcode just fine, like it was a real Mac. (However, the names of nearly all the (virtual) devices of the virtual machine have a "VMware" in them, which makes the VM not so real in the Apple's eyes if Xcode gathers and reports machine statistics during installation or app submission. In any case, even though Xcode might suspect that it's in an "alien" environment, it hasn't shown a single sign of it so far and works totally O.K.)

And, as the time of enrolling into the Apple's developer program is approaching, I wonder do I really have to shrink the development budget by $1000-$1500 or so to purchase a physical Mac as Apple would expect me to do. It's a significant amount of money and I would rather save them for something more useful. I would really like to avoid the purchase. (Un)fortunately, the times when people would buy Macs to lick them, as Steve Jobs' famous words would suggest, are over.

So, my questions are:

1. Has anyone heard of or maybe experienced fruitful development of iOS apps on a virtual OS X machine, which would mean getting an iOS app signing certificate to be used by Xcode running on that VM, and actually submitting an app to the App Store from the VM?
2. Even if such thing is technically possible, are there any legal obstacles buried somewhere in the license agreement(s) I would have to agree to while enrolling into the Apple's developer program? (Ahh, something's telling me there are..)

Comment: Why fix what ain't broken?  We're not hardware engineers, after all

Comment: If you're afraid of Xcode spying on you, which I don't think you should be, just export your IPA onto a thumb drive and then submit it via a Mac at an Apple Store. Once you become an overnight millionaire, buy a used Mac mini off Craigslist for $200.

Comment: Buy a second hand Mac Mini off eBay/Craigslist - end of story ;)

Comment: “We made the buttons on the screen look so good you'll want to lick them.” Attractive things make people feel good, which in turn makes them think more creatively, and be more patience and forgiving. It also shows attention to detail, that the users reward buying your product.

Answer (score 10):

**Technical:** I don't personally know of anybody developing for iOS in a VM. I don't see why it wouldn't work (the compiler should output the same stuff). It seems like a hassle.

**Legal:** The Mac OS X license agreement (Apple Menu, select "About This Mac", click "License Agreement" at the bottom of the window) only grants you permission to run Mac OS X on Apple-branded hardware, or in virtual environments that are running on Apple-branded hardware.

My gut says if you want to be a cheapskate, work out of a VM, and submit what you make to the App Store, you probably can. I don't think Xcode is spying on you in the ways you suggest.

Comment: @MilesHughes If somebody has done it and was willing to volunteer that fact, they would have done so by now. You've done the hard part (getting OS X running in a VM) and nobody can think of a reason why it won't work. So just go ahead, and if you run into a problem you can ask a more specific question about it.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK the software can detect if it is running on a VM (checking the CPUID hypervisor or the VMWare BIOS) but not if the hardware underneath is Apple or not. Because VMWare on Apple hardware can legally run Lion, it is highly likely you will succeed. Apple, unlike Microsoft, invest little effort enforcing licenses. The idea of Xcode trying to detect if it is inside a VM on non Apple hardware sounds very much unlike Apple.

Answer (score 3):

For $600 you can have a brand new Mac Mini. If you spend more than 5 hours keeping a hackintosh working with the newest Xcode/OSX over the next three years, you're wasting money. Seems a terrible investment to me, unless you have so many developer hours available that your time is insanely cheap.

For $800 you can have an Apple refurbed Macbook Air. These are just the official Apple sales. There are all kinds of used Macs on eBay.

Regarding #2, see @benzado's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard no stories of people developing Mac OS/iOS from a VM, of course it's the cheap easy solution since not everyone can afford a Mac.

I'd say it's a matter of what risks your willing to take, if as you say everything has a VM prefix, then this might reach Apple when you submit your app and you know how extremely picky they are about working in their own walled garden. My suggestion would be to cover your back and bite the bullet and get the Mac. Because then, if you go ahead and get the license and submit your app, you might get rejected, forcing you to go through the appeals system, and they already deny apps for a lot of stuff as to add another one willingly to the list.